# returning a list from an objects elements?

Tags: python, object

I have a defined an object ( simplified below) and want to return an element as a list.

Is there an easier way than doing the below ?

```
class objectRecord(object):
    def __init__(self,fields):
        self.time=fields[0]
        self.definition=fields[1]
        self.name=fields[2]
        self.source=fields[3]
        self.size=fields[4]
        self.value=fields[5]
        self.increasedsize=fields[6]
        self.count=fields[7]
```

rest of `__init__` omitted

```
    def getList(self):
        return [self.name,self.definition,self.name,self.source,self.size,self.value,self.increasedsize,self.count]
```

rest of class omitted

Comment: Keep in mind you can run into dangerous territory when you ask to do something "easier". You often end up with something that might be less lines of code, but also is a little more difficult to understand. This reminds me of a quote by Brian Kernighan: "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it." Also, keep in mind the Tao of Python: "Explicit is better than implicit". I'd recommend taking a step back and seeing if there's a different way altogether.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a dictionary containing all object attributes:

```
def get_attrs_dict(self):
    return self.__dict__
```

If you just want the list of values:

```
def get_attrs_list(self):
    return self.__dict__.values()
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to do it, via `getattr()`:

```
def getList(self):
    attributes = 'time definition name source'.split()
    return [getattr(self, attribute) for attribute in attributes]
```

You can add more attributes to the list if needed.

Answer (score 0):

As sort of a follow-up to Mark's comment: it looks an awful lot like what you actually want is to write your `__init__` like this:

```
def __init__(self, fields):
    self.fields = fields # or maybe fields[:] if you need to make a copy
    self.definition, self.name, ... , self.count = self.fields
```

This is both a more convenient way to define your variables, and provides a very clear way to access all the values (through `self.fields`).

Comment: So part of the missing init is that the fields may be either x or x+1 in length depending on when the object is called. So the __init__ would have to be modified for this eventuality.